# Adding MVC 5 to Web form application cannot get web.config in Views folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-mvc-5

I am adding a mvc 5.2.3 nuget package to an existing we form application. After I creating a controllers folder I create a controller. Than I add a view which creates a View automatically but it doesnot create a we.config file in the Views folder. Also I am getting an error The 'ViewBag' doesnot exists in the current context. I looked in all stackoverflow answers but doesnot solve my error. It does work If I create an Area. But I dont want to create Areas for my application.

Comment: If you somehow lost the web.config file you can just copy it from another compatible project.

Comment: Create an MVC 5 project, copy its web.config file inside Views folder to your existing webform project Views directory and edit it to match webform project spec. Also, you need to reference System.Web.Mvc in your project for ViewBag, ViewData & TempData usage.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the properties of the web.config file. I set the Build Action to Content and Copy to Output directory to Do not copy.